# How to change each feature styling in one vector layer in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to add features with different styling to a vector layer. I have a multiple lines which I want to have each one of them with different styling, but it looks like the styling I set for each feature were not affected. In other examples that I saw they had to have a unique layer to each styling.

Is there an option to add unique styling to each feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeap, you can use something like:

```
feature.setStyle(style1);
sourceFeatures.addFeature(feature);
```

Here is [an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/hhEAWk?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a way to do it and made a fiddle in case someone else want to do it:

[Multiple path vector layer](http://jsfiddle.net/vu8ecy8v/68/)

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            style: 'Road',
            source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'})
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        center: [-8908887.277395891, 5381918.072437216],
        maxZoom: 19,
        zoom: 2,
    }),
});

var colorArr = ['blue','green','orange']
var featureCount = 100;
var features=[];
var feature, geometry;
var e = 25000000;
var points = [];
for (i = 0; i < featureCount; ++i) {
    colorindex = Math.abs(parseInt((Math.random()*3).toFixed())-1);
    if(i%10){
        points.push([2 * e * Math.random() - e, 2 * e * Math.random() - e]);
    continue;
    }

  feature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(points, 'XY')
        });
  feature.setStyle(
      new ol.style.Style({
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: colorArr[colorindex],opacity: 0.7}),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: colorArr[colorindex], width: 4,opacity: 0.7
          })
      })
  );
  features.push(feature);
  points = [];
}
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: features
});
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

map.addLayer(vector);
```

Comment: just added it the, I had logic problem in my code and  I was able to change the path color, but the problem was that I was drawing the whole path as one path above the paths before so I thought openlayers it takes by default the last styling... which caused my to ask this question..